# this inside prototype function equal to window instead of object instance

Tags: javascript, this, typescript, browserify

In the following code in `HeadDirective.prototype.link`, `this` is equal to the global `window` object rather than the `HeadDirective` instance. My understanding is that the value of `this` inside a prototype function is the containing object itself.

```js
var HeadDirective = (function () {
    function HeadDirective($rootScope, $compile) {
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.$compile = $compile;
        this.restrict = 'E';
    }
    HeadDirective.prototype.link = function (scope, elem) {
        var html = '<link rel="stylesheet" ng-repeat="cssUrl in routeStyles" ng-href="{{cssUrl}}" />';
        elem.append(this.$compile(html)(scope));
        scope.routeStyles = [];
        this.$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (e, next, current) {
            if (next && next.$$route && next.$$route.css) {
                if (!Array.isArray(next.$$route.css)) {
                    next.$$route.css = [next.$$route.css];
                }
                angular.forEach(next.$$route.css, function (sheet) {
                    scope.routeStyles.push(sheet);
                });
            }
        });
        this.$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, next, current) {
            if (current && current.$$route && current.$$route.css) {
                if (!Array.isArray(current.$$route.css)) {
                    current.$$route.css = [current.$$route.css];
                }
                angular.forEach(current.$$route.css, function (sheet) {
                    scope.routeStyles.splice(scope.routeStyles.indexOf(sheet), 1);
                });
            }
        });
    };
    return HeadDirective;
})();

directives.directive('head', [
    '$rootScope', '$compile', function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        return new HeadDirective($rootScope, $compile);
    }]);
```

The above code was generated from the following TypeScript:

```typescript
class HeadDirective implements ng.IDirective {

    constructor(private $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, private $compile: ng.ICompileService) {}

    link(scope: IScope, elem: JQuery): void {
        var html = '<link rel="stylesheet" ng-repeat="cssUrl in routeStyles" ng-href="{{cssUrl}}" />';
        elem.append(this.$compile(html)(scope));
        scope.routeStyles = [];
        this.$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', (e: ng.IAngularEvent, next?: IRoute, current?: IRoute): any => {
            if(next && next.$$route && next.$$route.css){
                if(!Array.isArray(next.$$route.css)){
                    next.$$route.css = [next.$$route.css];
                }
                angular.forEach(next.$$route.css, (sheet: string) => {
                    scope.routeStyles.push(sheet);
                });
            }
        });
        this.$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', (e: ng.IAngularEvent, next?: IRoute, current?: IRoute): any => {
            if(current && current.$$route && current.$$route.css){
                if(!Array.isArray(current.$$route.css)){
                    current.$$route.css = [current.$$route.css];
                }
                angular.forEach(current.$$route.css, (sheet) => {
                    scope.routeStyles.splice(scope.routeStyles.indexOf(sheet), 1);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    restrict = 'E';
}

directives.directive('head', ['$rootScope','$compile', ($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $compile: ng.ICompileService): ng.IDirective =>{
    return new HeadDirective($rootScope, $compile);
}]);
```

According to the latest TypeScript language specification:

> The type of `this` in an expression depends on the location in which the reference takes place:
>
> - In a constructor, **instance member function**, instance member accessor, or instance member variable initializer, `this` is of the class instance type of the containing class.
> - In a static member function or static member accessor, the type of `this` is the constructor function type of the containing class.
> - In a function declaration or a standard function expression, `this` is of type Any.
> - In the global module, `this` is of type Any.
>
> In all other contexts it is a compile-time error to reference this.

The TypeScript language specification is quite clear. Inside a member function (which is compiled into a prototype function), `this` refers to the class instance. This is obviously not what I'm seeing.

Any ideas? Could Browserify be interfering with `this`?

Comment: A video on `this` in typescript : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `this` keyword is highly contextual. If a method is called by an event, `this` will be the object that is the event target, for example.

You can get around *this* problem by shimmying `this` into a variable, or by using the JavaScript `call` (or `apply`) methods to bind the scope of `this`.

Short example... here is the premise:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(private myProp: string) {

    }

    myMethod() {
        alert(this.myProp);
    }
}

var myClass = new MyClass('Test');

// 'Test'
myClass.myMethod();

// undefined
window.setTimeout(myClass.myMethod, 1000);
```

## Solution One - Arrow Syntax

In TypeScript the arrow syntax will shimmy `this` into a variable called `_this` automatically for you and substitute usages inside the arrow function... So this will solve the `undefined` issue above and instead alert `Test`.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(private myProp: string) {

    }

    public myMethod = () => {
        alert(this.myProp);
    }
}
```

## Solution Two - Call Method

You can use the `call` method to replace the contextual `this` with any object you like, in the example below we reset it to be the `myClass` instance.

This works whether you are writing TypeScript or plain JavaScript... whereas the first solution is really a TypeScript solution.

```
window.setTimeout(function() { myClass.myMethod.call(myClass) }, 1000);
```

Or to be shorter (to be clear, the use of the arrow function here has nothing to do with scope - it is just a shorter syntax *arrow functions only affect scope if you have `this` inside of them*):

```
window.setTimeout(() => myClass.myMethod.call(myClass), 1000);
```

Comment: Would you say, then, that the TypeScript language specification makes a promise it cannot keep?

Comment: The spec is describing the *compile-time type* of the `this` keyword in the section you quoted, not the value. Because TypeScript has the same `this` semantics as JavaScript at runtime, it's always going to be possible to end up with the 'wrong' value.

Comment: OK. If `this` inside an object's constructors, methods, accessors and mutators isn't always equal to the class instance itself, then there is no point having classes. If I want JavaScript semantics, I'll use JavaScript.

Comment: @SteveTaylor I understand your frustration - but actually you will want to choose when to use `this` as the instance and `this` as the context. Event handling, for example, works much better if you can use `this` in context.

Comment: Yes, I want to at least be able to **choose** without ugly hacks (e.g. shoving everything into the constructor, thereby not being able to implement interfaces and generally making the `class` and constructor keywords no better than comments). Failing choice, I much prefer what all other languages with classes have, which is a built-in, guaranteed method of accessing an instance from its own **instance** methods.

Comment: My second solution leaves the class entirely untouched. It is less defensive, but the class design is then left "pure".

Comment: Silly me - I just re-read **Solution One** and realized it's what I'm looking for - a way to write instance methods where `this` is guaranteed to be the instance method's instance. If I had read it properly, I wouldn't have had to independently discover it was added in TypeScript 0.9.1. Thanks!

Comment: No problems - glad it helped :)